# how to identify topic and data type mapping in ros

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I want to know the exact data type of  topic published. So in some scenario    data type integer related information published under some topics or it might be image or string data. in some scenario published information under topic might be collection of  some of the data types (int, bool, string, float, double) . so how to identify through command line or API  what data type is published under particular topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269762/how-to-identify-topic-and-data-type-mapping-in-ros/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For command line usage you can run `rostopic info <topic-name>` and that will show the message type along with other information. Here's an example with just `roscore` running.

```
$ rostopic info /rosout
Type: rosgraph_msgs/Log

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /rosout (http://127.0.0.1:41588/)
```

Notice the section that says

```
Type: rosgraph_msgs/Log
```

this shows that this topic carries messages of the type `rosgraph_msgs/Log`. You can read more about this on the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_info_.28ROS_0.10.29).

---

**Edit:**

As @gvdhoorn pointed out in the comments, a great shortcut is

```
rostopic type /my_topic | rosmsg show
```

which will then show (from my above example)

```
$ rostopic type /rosout | rosmsg show

byte DEBUG=1
byte INFO=2
byte WARN=4
byte ERROR=8
byte FATAL=16
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
byte level
string name
string msg
string file
string function
uint32 line
string[] topics
```

which gives the definition of the message.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-28**:
Shortcut: `rostopic type /my_topic | rosmsg show`.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
@gvdhoorn, thanks I didn't know about that one. I'll update my answer with it.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-17**:
@can-43811 if this answered your question, please click on the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.